# PolynomialQ always yields True?

Tags: polynomials, expression-test

I have a question about the PolynomialQ function in Mathematica. I have the polynomial (this is the Chebyshev's polynomial of the first kind)

$$B=\frac{1}{2} ([x - \sqrt{(-1 + x^2)}]^n + [x + \sqrt{[-1 + x^2]}]^n)$$

Which I generate recursively

```
cheb = RSolve[{T[n + 1] == 2 x T[n] - T[n - 1], T[1] == x, T[0] == 1}, T[n], n]
B[x_, n_] := T[n] /. cheb[[1]]
```

Now assume I want to check whether this is truly a polynomial for n=0 to n=9. I use the PolynomialQ

```
Table[PolynomialQ[B[x, n], x], {n, 0, 9}]
```

And am given the answer
{True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False};

I assumed this is the problem of simplification, thereby I added a FullSimplify in front of the B:

```
Table[PolynomialQ[FullSimplify[B[x, n]], x], {n, 0, 9}]
```

This however, makes it really don't matter what argument I add in the polynomial. The answer is always 10xTrue for every argument except n, when it is {True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True}, which doesn't make any sense regardless.

I believe I am deeply misunderstanding PolynomialQ, because that is the only way I see why this would not work. Could someone give me a hint as to what I'm doing is wrong?

Comment: You have an `n` that should be an `x`, I think: `Table[PolynomialQ[Simplify[B[x, n]], x], {n, 0, 9}]`.

Comment: It doesn't really matter; If I put an x I get 10 True's. If I put an n I get {True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True}. If I put anything else, whether it be y, z, dog, aaa I get true. This is what I don't get.

Comment: I can run it with `Table[PolynomialQ[FullSimplify[B[x, n]], aaaaa], {n, 0, 9}]` and it will still yield `True`, though, which is what puzzles me.

Comment: So you would say, that if I use `Table[PolynomialQ[FullSimplify[B[x, n]], x], {n, 0, 9}]` the result is not an artefact, but it actually checks whether my function is a polynomial with respect to `x`?
Seeing how it responded to other variables, I am not sure I can 'trust' the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69983/discussion-between-michael-e2-and-henrikas).

Comment: "the result is not an artefact, but it actually checks whether my function is a polynomial with respect to `x`?" - yes. Consider the simpler `PolynomialQ[y, x]`; a *constant* is still counted as a polynomial, and since `D[y, x] == 0`, `y` is a constant with respect to `x`. As for your Chebyshev polynomials: if you want to check things yourself, you can separate out the generation and checking: `polys = Table[FullSimplify[1/2 ((x - Sqrt[-1 + x^2])^n + (x + Sqrt[-1 + x^2])^n)], {n, 0, 9}]` and then `PolynomialQ[#, x] & /@ polys`.